# What's wrong with my Spring XML Beans config file?

Tags: xml, spring, oauth, xsd, xsi

**security.xml**
 I am getting the following errors :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
     xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
     xsi:schemaLocation=" 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org./schema/security
            http://www.springframework.org./schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd">

    <!-- Definition of authentication service -->
    <http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
          xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
          <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
          <anonymous enabled="false"/>
          <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
          <!--  Include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters-->
          <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIX_AUTH_FILTER"/>
          <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>      
    </http>

    <!--  Protected resources-->
    <http pattern="/country/**"
          create-session="never"
          entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
          xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
         <anonymous enabled="false"/>
         <intercept-url pattern="/country/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
         <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter"
                        before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
         <access-denied-handler 
                    ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/> 
    </http>

    <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
            <property name="realmName" value="dstest"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="clienthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
            <property name="realmName" value="dstest/client"/>
            <property name="typeName" value="Basic"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler">
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
          <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
          xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
        <constructor-arg>
          <list>
             <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter"/>
             <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter"/>
             <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>
          </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!--  Authentication in config file -->
    <authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager"
                            xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
          <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService"/>                    
    </authentication-manager>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
       <authentication-provider>
            <user-service id="userDetailsService">
               <user name="admin" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER"/> 
            </user-service>
       </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
            <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails"/>
    </bean>        

    <!--  Token Store -->
    <bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore"/>

    <bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
          <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
          <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true"/>
          <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails"/>
          <!--  VIV -->
          <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="10"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userApprovalHandler"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
        <property name="tokenService" ref="tokenServices"/>
    </bean>

    <!--  Token Management -->
    <oauth:authrization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
                                        user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
            <oauth:authrization-code/>
            <oauth:implicit/>
            <oauth:refresh-token/>
            <oauth:client-credentials/>
            <oauth:password/>                                   
    </oauth:authrization-server>

    <!--  Client Definition -->
    <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">

            <oauth:client client-id="my-trusted-client"
            authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit,redirect"
            authorities="ROLE_CLIENT, ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT"
            redirect-uri="/web"
            scope="read,write,trust"
            access-token-validity="60"
            refresh-token-validity="600"/>
    </oauth:client-details-service>

    <sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
            <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler"/>
    </sec:global-method-security>

    <oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler"/>
    <oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler"/>

    </beans>
```

I am getting the following errors:

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no
>   declaration can be found for element 'authentication-manager'.
>
> cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no
>   declaration can be found for element 'http'.
>
> cvc-complex-type.2.4.c:    The matching wildcard is strict, but no
>   declaration can be found for    element 'oauth:authrization-server'.
>
> cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The    matching wildcard is strict, but no
>   declaration can be found for element 'sec:global-method-security'.

I have referred several links I have added all the dependencies required still I am not able to figure out what these error are. This is my first time working on spring-security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSD validation will provide informative errors, but you have to watch the typos, especially in the namespace declarations, or the right subordinate XSDs will not even be able to be read.

**You have four problems to fix to get to a valid document:**

1. Change

   ```
       http://www.springframework.org./schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org./schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd
   ```

   to

   ```
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd
   ```
2. Change `oauth:authrization-server` to `oauth:authorization-server`.
3. Change `oauth:authrization-code` to `oauth:authrization-code`.
4. Change `BASIX_AUTH_FILTER` to `BASIC_AUTH_FILTER`

Comment: i have added the spring-security-config-4.1.x dependency to my pom.xml..

Comment: Looking at your XML more closely, I've identified 4 fixes you must make.  Answer updated.

Comment: I found the first 2 typos later, just fixed all, Working fine Thanks.. :)